# JavaScript vs jQuery math behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm experimenting building a game in javascript. I had this function to move a character:

```
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
        let p = document.getElementById('player'), x = p.offsetLeft, y = p.offsetTop;
        console.log({x,y});
        switch( e.keyCode ) {
            case 37:
                x -= 1.5;
            break;
            case 38:
                y -= 1.5; 
            break;
            case 39:
                x += 1.5;
            break;
            case 40:
                y += 1.5;
            break;
        }
        console.log({x,y});
        p.setAttribute('style', `left: ${x}px; top:${y}px;`);
    });
```

and this is the same function but written with jQuery:

```
    $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
        let x = $('#player').offset().left, y = $('#player').offset().top;
        switch(e.keyCode) {
            case 37:
                x -= 1.5;
            break;
            case 38:
                y -= 1.5; 
            break;
            case 39:
                x += 1.5;
            break;
            case 40:
                y += 1.5;
            break;
        }
        $('#player').css({
            top: y + "px",
            left: x + "px" 
        });
    });
```

Why does the function written in vanilla javascript move the object faster to the right than the left, while jQuery moves the same speed in both directions?
Edit: Forgot to mention, this only happens with this particular value 1.5, for let's say 1 is just ok.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `offset()` is able to handle half a pixel:

> The number returned by dimensions-related APIs, including .offset(), may be fractional in some cases. Code should not assume it is an integer. http://api.jquery.com/offset/

offsetLeft and offsetTop work in integers only, so rounds your 1.5 up to 2, therefore moving the object farther at each step (in both directions):

> left is an integer representing the offset to the left in pixels from the closest relatively positioned parent element.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
        let p = document.getElementById('player'), x = p.offsetLeft, y = p.offsetTop;
        console.log("vanilla: ", x, y);
        switch( e.keyCode ) {
            case 37:
                x -= 1.5;
            break;
            case 38:
                y -= 1.5; 
            break;
            case 39:
                x += 1.5;
            break;
            case 40:
                y += 1.5;
            break;
        }
        p.setAttribute('style', `left: ${x}px; top:${y}px;`);
    });

    $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
        let x = $('#jqPlayer').offset().left, y = $('#jqPlayer').offset().top;
        console.log("jQuery: ", x, y);

        switch(e.keyCode) {
            case 37:
                x -= 1.5;
            break;
            case 38:
                y -= 1.5; 
            break;
            case 39:
                x += 1.5;
            break;
            case 40:
                y += 1.5;
            break;
        }
        $('#jqPlayer').css({
            top: y + "px",
            left: x + "px" 
        });
    });
```

```css
div.obj {position:absolute; border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="obj" id="player">vanilla</div>

<div class="obj" id="jqPlayer">jQuery</div>
```

As confirmation, if you stick to whole numbers, the difference disappears:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
        let p = document.getElementById('player'), x = p.offsetLeft, y = p.offsetTop;
        switch( e.keyCode ) {
            case 37:
                x -= 2;
            break;
            case 38:
                y -= 2; 
            break;
            case 39:
                x += 2;
            break;
            case 40:
                y += 2;
            break;
        }
        p.setAttribute('style', `left: ${x}px; top:${y}px;`);
    });

    $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
        let x = $('#jqPlayer').offset().left, y = $('#jqPlayer').offset().top;
        switch(e.keyCode) {
            case 37:
                x -= 2;
            break;
            case 38:
                y -= 2; 
            break;
            case 39:
                x += 2;
            break;
            case 40:
                y += 2;
            break;
        }
        $('#jqPlayer').css({
            top: y + "px",
            left: x + "px" 
        });
    });
```

```css
div.obj {position:absolute; border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="obj" id="player">vanilla</div>

<div class="obj" id="jqPlayer">jQuery</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

When you retrieve the `x` and `y` using `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft`, the values are **rounded**.

The effect is that the left arrow key is adding `0.5` via rounding, then adding `-1.5` for a net movement of **`-1`**. The right arrow key is adding `0.5` via rounding, then adding `1.5` for a net movement of **`+2`**.

For example, compare the value of `offsetLeft` before and after adding `1.5`:

```js
let p = document.getElementById('player');
const results = [];

const incrementAndRetrieveOffset = () => {
  let result = {},
      x = p.offsetLeft;
  result["Initial X Offset"] = x;
  x += 1.5;
  p.setAttribute('style', `left: ${x}px;`);
  result["+1.5"] = p.offsetLeft;
  results.push(result);
};

for (let i=0; i<5; ++i ) 
  incrementAndRetrieveOffset();

console.log("Re-run with Browser console open to see tabular data...");
console.table(results);
```

```css
#player {position: absolute;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Because `$(Element).offset().left` **is not** `Element.offsetLeft`.

The first big difference, even though it may not be the one you face today is that the former is relative to the viewport while the latter is relative to the `offsetParent`.

This means that you may not have the same values at all.

```js
console.log('$.offset()', $('#test').offset().left);
console.log('offsetLeft', test.offsetLeft);
console.log('getBoundingClientRect', test.getBoundingClientRect().left);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
#test{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper"><div id="test"></div></div>
```

The second difference is that the latter is rounded.

You may want to use [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) instead, which is also relative to the viewport and also supports decimal precision.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  let p = document.getElementById('player_1'),
    bbox = p.getBoundingClientRect(),
    x = bbox.left,
    y = bbox.top;
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      x -= 1.5;
      break;
    case 38:
      y -= 1.5;
      break;
    case 39:
      x += 1.5;
      break;
    case 40:
      y += 1.5;
      break;
  }
  p.setAttribute('style', `left: ${x}px; top:${y}px;`);
});

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  let x = $('#player_2').offset().left,
    y = $('#player_2').offset().top;

  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      x -= 1.5;
      break;
    case 38:
      y -= 1.5;
      break;
    case 39:
      x += 1.5;
      break;
    case 40:
      y += 1.5;
      break;
  }
  $('#player_2').css({
    top: y + "px",
    left: x + "px"
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
div.obj {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid
}

#player_2 {
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="obj" id="player_1">vanilla</div>

<div class="obj" id="player_2">jQuery</div>
```